# WordPress: Syncronize multiple databases data

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have two websites, one which is the main site, and one which is a secondary website.
Both are **woocommerce** and both the websites have the same products in the database BUT different customers/users.

What I currently do manually is: Create/modify a product on the main website, and then copy/paste to the secondary one.

I would love to make this becoming automatic, so every time something gets updated/modified in the products table from the main website, it will automatically update the second one too (**and not vice versa**).

I know there are already some plugins for WordPress but I would love to know from you which one you suggest for this purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can also use woocommerce webhooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few solutions:

1. There is an option to set which tables a site uses, i.e. if the first site has table tb1_products and the second one tb2_products, in wp_config you can tell the second website to use the table for the first site. However, this requires all tables for both sites to be under the same database. Something like for the user's tables:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', $table_prefix.'users')
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', $table_prefix.'usersmeta')
```

As you already have your sites up and running, I presume you have them on separate databases, so another two are your options:

2. Use a plugin like [Woo Multistore](https://woomultistore.com/)
3. Use [Woo CommerceAPI](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) to keep the site A products in sync as soon as a site B product changes.
4. One more plugin (free): [Stock Sync for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stock-sync-for-woocommerce/)